# AngularJS ng-class add/remove animation do not apply/fire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, ng-animate, ng-class

I'm trying to add an animation on add/remove on the `<a>`-Tag, based on the `toggleBookmark` function. The active class is added when it returns true and works fine.
However, the `ng-add` or `icon__bookmark-add` animation does not fire on the `<a>` tag.

Why? What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="event in events | filter:searchText">
  <div ng-click="toggleBookmark(event.id)" class="events-list__icons">
    <a ng-class="{active:isBookmarked(event.id)}" class="icon__bookmark"></a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.isBookmarked = (id) ->
  BookmarkService.isBookmarked(id) // this just returns true or false

$scope.toggleBookmark = (id) ->
  BookmarkService.toggleBookmark(id) // returns nothing
```

CSS:

```
.icon__bookmark.ng-add,
.icon__bookmark.ng-add-active,
.icon__bookmark-add,
.icon__bookmark-add-active {
  animation: flip .6s ease-in-out;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: "However the `ng-add` or `icon__bookmark-add` animation does not fire..." - Where is this defined and how have you defined it?

Comment: it's defined in the css. edited my post above.

Comment: Your `ng-class` attribute is conditionally adding the class `active`. You have no styles for that class. For example, `.icon__bookmark.active`.

Comment: I do have styles for `.active`... but what I want instead is the .ng-add and .ng-add-active classes, which get removed after they finished playing.

Answer (score 3):

`ng-class="{active:isBookmarked(event.id)}"` only adds the class `active`.

You should redefine your CSS so that 'active' runs the animation. See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolasmoise/XaL9r/1/

You can also use the ngAnimate service and create a new directive for .events-list__icons.

```
$animate.addClass(element, 'active')
```

Would add `active`, `active-add` (to set up the animation), and `active-add-active` (to run the animation) classes.

Comment: This is exactly correct:  using the bracket format rather than just having an individual class did it for me.